# Refresh Rate and after function in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a GUI using python which contains different buttons flickering at certain frequencies. This was achieved by employing "after" function from tkinter library. However the refresh rate f the screen is affecting the real frequencies and the expected one(12Hz).  Could someone please explain or guide me how refresh rates would after the function and how it can be dealt.

Below code snippet is a function to make a button blink at 12 Hz

```
 def flash_back(self):
        bottombg = self.bottombutton.cget("background")
        bottomfg = self.bottombutton.cget("foreground")
        self.bottombutton.configure(background=bottomfg, foreground=bottombg)
        self.bottombutton.after(83, self.flash_back) #12 Hz
```